# Display the Toast message when i was clicking the disabled check box

Tags: android, web-services, checkbox

I used web service, I get the check box dynamically. But the check boxes are enabled by one by one. Suppose if i click first check box second check box only enable others are disabled, if check the second check box third check box only enable others are disabled and so on...
So I need to display Toast if i click the disabled check box.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you manually disable the uncheck CheckBoxes, then you should be able to get that through the view state of .isEnabled() when it is clicked.

Comment: Yes i manually disable the check box. I need to display the Toast when perform the action, that means if i click the disabled check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);


     if (checkBox.isChecked()) {

     }else{
   //display toast here...

}
```

Comment: I need to display the Toast when perform the action, that means if i click the disabled check boxes.

Comment: @RajeshPradeep whats problem with this answer? Show your Toast in If Condition.

Comment: if i run the above code, The toast automatically displayed, I ask toast display only if i click(Touch) the disabled check boxes.

Comment: ok so then put this method inside your on click listener for the button, and check for all buttons that are unchecked and send a toast

Comment: Does not work, Check or unchecked that does not a matter, display the toast only if i click(Touch) the DISABLED check boxes.